# how to publish and subscribe channels  dynamically ? 

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, socket.io

//Server setting....

```
//Store using Redis ..


 this is the part of the code, now i have to send the stored data to other clients connected,the case is 'n' no.of application with 'n' no.of clients, so i have to create channels here dynamically. am asking u to help me by giving ideas for creating dynamic channel name for pub/sub.
```

Comment: Improve question or else this question will get my vote to be closed also.

Answer (score 2):

This is not something Redis handles. You'll need to protect access to Redis pub/sub through an application layer. If you want to allow people to connect *directly* to Redis and still protect channels per user, I believe you're out of luck.

Comment: :What to do , if I want to make sure only certain users can subscribe to certain channels (based on their server-side permissions)? Exclude that redis pub/sub...

Comment: Are you talking about them connecting directly to Redis? If so, you cannot do that. If not, you'll have to provide more details, as your question is very vague.

Comment: @ brandon-tilley : not connecting directly to redis, just i wanna store the data passing through socket in redis..... and publishing and subscribing thru redis..

Comment: We don't know anything about your application structure or what you've tried so far; this is an impossible question to answer with the information given. Please expand upon your question by editing it.